# How to show that a Brownian motion is normally distributed and that the covariance is zero?

Tags: brownian-motion, econometrics, financial

I need help under standing this question. So i have the following given the logarithm of the price of a share of stock is given by

\begin{align*}
p(t)=p(0)+\mu t+\sigma W(t), \quad t \in[0, T]
\end{align*}
where $p(0) \in \mathbb{R}$ is some fixed initial value, $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\sigma>0$ are constants, and $W(t)$ is a Brownian motion.

I know that the Brownian motion $W(t)$ has the properties

1. $W(0)=0$
2. $W$ has independent increments, i.e. if $0 \leq r<s \leq t<u,$ then
   \begin{align*}
   W(u)-W(t) \text { and } W(s)-W(r)
   \end{align*}
   are independent.
3. The increments are normally distributed, i.e.
   \begin{align*}
   W(t)-W(s) \sim N(0, t-s)
   \end{align*}
   for all $0 \leq s \leq t$.
   Suppose that we have observed the price $p(t)$ at $n+1$ equidistant points
   \begin{align*}
   0=t_{0}<t_{1}<\ldots<t_{n}=T
   \end{align*}
   with
   \begin{align*}
   t_{i}=\frac{i}{n} T, \quad i=0, \ldots, n
   \end{align*}
   I am given that the $n$ log-returns given as
   \begin{align*}
   r\left(t_{i}\right)=p\left(t_{i}\right)-p\left(t_{i-1}\right), \quad i=1, \ldots, n
   \end{align*}

I need to show the following

$r\left(t_{i}\right) \sim N\left(\mu \frac{T}{n}, \sigma^{2} \frac{T}{n}\right)$ and that $\operatorname{cov}\left(r\left(t_{i}\right), r\left(t_{i-1}\right)\right)=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Normality of returns** follows from the fact that the Brownian increments are normal distributed (property 3), $W(t_i)-W(t_{i-1}) \sim N(0,t_i-t_{i-1})$, and furthermore that $t_i-t_{i-1}=T(\frac{i}{n}-\frac{i-1}{n})=\frac{T}{n}$. See that:

\begin{align}
r(t_i)&=p(t_i)-p(t_{i-1})\\
&=\left[p(0)+\mu\cdot t_i + \sigma W(t_i) \right] - \left[p(0)+\mu\cdot t_{i-1} + \sigma W(t_{i-1}) \right]\\
&= \mu (t_i-t_{i-1})+\sigma(W(t_i)-W(t_{i-1}))\\
&\overset{d}{=} \mu (t_i-t_{i-1}) + N\left(0,\sigma^2(t_i-t_{i-1})\right)\\
&=N\left(\mu\frac{T}{n},\sigma^2 \frac{T}{n}\right)
\end{align}
Now, **the covariance of the returns** follows directly from the independent increments property of Brownian motions. Under an alternative notation, $W(t_i)=W_{t_i}$, we have:

\begin{align}
\small{Cov\left(r(t_i),r(t_{i-1})\right)} &= \small{\sigma^2 Cov\left(W_{t_i}-W_{t_{i-1}},\: W_{t_{i-1}}-W_{t_{i-2}} \right)}\\
&=\small{\sigma^2 \cdot (\mathbb{E}\left[(W_{t_{i}}-W_{t_{i-1}})\cdot (W_{t_{i-1}}-W_{t_{i-2}})\right]-\mathbb{E}\left[W_{t_{i}}-W_{t_{i-1}}\right]\cdot \mathbb{E}\left[W_{t_{i-1}}-W_{t_{i-2}}\right])}\\
&=\small{\sigma^2 \cdot (\mathbb{E}\left[(W_{t_{i}}-W_{t_{i-1}})\cdot (W_{t_{i-1}}-W_{t_{i-2}})\right] - 0)}\\
&=\small{\sigma^2 \cdot (\mathbb{E}\left[(W_{t_{i}}-W_{t_{i-1}})\right] \mathbb{E}\left[(W_{t_{i-1}}-W_{t_{i-2}})\right])}\\
&=\small{0},
\end{align}
where we have used the independent increments property in the last equation and furthermore that the increments have expectation zero.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to derive the expressions. This helped me alot :)